# how to understand .sc .mat in matlab

Tags: matlab

i cant see the logic of these two lines taken from the full code shown bellow.
i know that its some how plotting an area
but .mat .sc are resembling . command from c# of object oriented.
matlab is not object oriented
How to understand the meaning of the two lines shown bellow?

```
func_in.mat=NmidCirc;
func_in.sc=scale;
```

Thanks.
full code:

```
lambda=633e-9;% wave length in [m]
L=0.01;% meter factor, it is defined that 1cm=1024 pixels-> the first scale will be over 1cm
scale=linspace(-L/2,L/2,n);% basic scaling vector in length of 1024.
%% Q2 creating matrix
[X, Y]= meshgrid(scale,scale);% creating the basic function. on the function we will create the images that will operated
midCirc= X.^2+Y.^2<(1/n)^2;%because we work in meter units, the 100/1024[cm] transforms into 1/1024[m]
NmidCirc=not(midCirc);
Ring= ((X-0.8/n).^2+(Y-0.8/n).^2<(1/n)^2)&((X-0.8/n).^2+(Y-0.8/n).^2>(0.6/n)^2);
NRing=not(Ring);
Tshape= (abs(Y)<0.2/n)&(abs(X)<0.6/n) | ((Y<1.4/n)&(Y>0.2/n)&(abs(X)<0.2/n))


%%%% Negative cirle part
func_in.mat=NmidCirc;
func_in.sc=scale;
figure(2)
colormap gray
for j=1:6
     func_out=Rdiv(func_in,lambda,Z(j),n);
     subplot(2,3,j);
     image(func_out.sc, func_out.sc, abs(func_out.mat), 'CDataMapping','scaled');
     xlabel('[m]');
     ylabel('[m]');
     title(['Z=',num2str(Z(j))]);
end
```

Comment: But, matlab *is* object oriented. https://se.mathworks.com/products/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html  but what you have here is simpler, it's just a struct, which has existed in matlab for as long as I know.

Comment: Hello, i could not see these specific structs.Could you please give me an example so i could see how these structs work?
Thanks.